# Java Spring Boot - ModelMapper Unable to map fullName in the DTO from firstName & lastName

Tags: spring, spring-boot, modelmapper

I am learning spring boot and i have recetly learnt about `ModelMapper` library.

From `Student` Class, i am trying to map `firstName` and `lastName` into `fullName` from `StudentResponseDTO`.

Here is `Stduent` Object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private Integer age;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "school_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private School school;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private StudentProfile studentProfile;
}
```

And this is `StudentResponseDTO`:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class StudentResponseDTO {
    private String fullName;
    private String email;
}
```

I have created a modelmapper configuration class as below:

```
@Configuration
public class ModelMapperConfig {
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

//        Custom Mappings
        modelMapper.createTypeMap(StudentDTO.class, Student.class).addMapping(StudentDTO::getSchoolId, (dest, value) -> dest.getSchool().setId((Long) value));

        modelMapper.createTypeMap(Student.class, StudentResponseDTO.class).addMapping(src -> src.getFirstName() + " " + src.getLastName(), StudentResponseDTO::setFullName);

        return modelMapper;
    }
}
```

In my controller method, i use the mapper as follows:

```
@RequestMapping("api/v1/students")
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StudentController {
    private final StudentRepository repository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @GetMapping
    List<StudentResponseDTO> getAllStudent() {
        List<Student> studentsList = repository.findAll();

        List<StudentResponseDTO> response = studentsList.stream().map(student -> modelMapper.map(student, StudentResponseDTO.class)).toList();

        return response;
    }

}
```

I get this error when i hit the endpoint

```
2024-03-14T10:47:19.460+03:00 ERROR 16452 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Error mapping com.example.Spring.Boot.tutorial.model.entities.Student to com.example.Spring.Boot.tutorial.model.dto.StudentResponseDTO

1 error] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.checkReceiver(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:99) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.PropertyInfoImpl$MethodAccessor.getValue(PropertyInfoImpl.java:99) ~[modelmapper-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.resolveSourceValue(MappingEngineImpl.java:197) ~[modelmapper-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.propertyMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:170) ~[modelmapper-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:151) ~[modelmapper-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:105) ~[modelmapper-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:71) ~[modelmapper-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:589) ~[modelmapper-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:422) ~[modelmapper-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.example.Spring.Boot.tutorial.controller.StudentController.lambda$getAllStudent$1(StudentController.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:622) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toList(ReferencePipeline.java:627) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.Spring.Boot.tutorial.controller.StudentController.getAllStudent(StudentController.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:259) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:192) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
```